# Javascript call from inside Flash, within a Facebook Canvas App

Tags: facebook, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a Facebook Canvas iframe app. In that, I have a SWF object which needs to call a javascript function which is defined in my main facbebook app body.
The call is not being made, I'm guessing Facebook are stopping it.

There must be a way around this?

I am doing a test call like this from Flash (AS2):

```
getURL("javascript:alert(1);");
```

Do I need to try and capture the facebook iframe and use that in Flash?

Comment: Im not so sure "there must be a way around it". Security models in Facebook and in browsers in general are meant to prevent it.

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö I know there is a way around it because hundreds of Flash games in Facebook apps are doing it.

Comment: The stuff I mean there may not be a way around is mechanisms such as Facebook setting allowscriptaccess="never" on Flash content (not necessarily in your iframe) or JavaScript calls between frames of different origin being stopped. There may very well be a way of accomplishing what you want to accomplish, there usually is, but if your JavaScript call is stopped for security reasons, you may need to use another approach altogether.

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö there is way around it, see my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew there was a way around this. Put the flash in a HTML document and set `document.domain  = x`. In the body of the Canvas app, also set the same `document.domain = x`. Then use an iframe to show the flash's HTML document.

The flash then can make javascript calls and interact with your canvas app as needed.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ExternalInterface class:
[ExternalInterface Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

it's easy as ABC. for example this line of code will execute
the alert javascript function.

```
ExternalInterface.call("javascript:alert();");
```

Comment: Thanks but even using `ExternalInterface`, the call isn't made just like `getURL`

Comment: check your javascript code.
is the name of the function right?

Comment: yes the function name is right, see my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ExternalInterface class? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00001036.html

Comment: Thanks but even using `ExternalInterface`, the call isn't made just like `getURL`